# How to fix XML Nodes being inserted after closing

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am loading records from a sql database and inserting them into an XML tree, however the new records are being inserted after the list I want them in is closed.

I have tried using addafterself, addbeforeself both of these result in null reference exceptions.

This is my function I am using to fill the xml

```
 private void FillXml(List<ClientCrosswalk> clients)
        {

            XElement doc = XElement.Load(cFolder + @"\Files\emptyClientXMLMod.xml");
            List<XElement> elements = new List<XElement>();
            //Add the first client to the list to avoid overwriting
            foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("ClientLocation"))
            {
                elements.Add(node);
                node.Element("Description").Value = clients[0].AcctNo.ToString() + " " + clients[0].AcctName.ToString();
                node.Element("LocationName").Value = clients[0].DivCode.ToString();
            }
            clients.RemoveAt(0);
            doc.Save(cFolder + @"\Outbox\clientSIE.xml");
            //Build a new xml tree for each respective client and add it to the Client list
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                foreach (var elm in elements)
                {
                    elm.Element("Description").Value = client.AcctNo.ToString() + " " + client.AcctName.ToString();
                    elm.Element("LocationName").Value = client.DivCode.ToString();
                    doc.Add(elm);
                }
            }
            doc.Save(cFolder + @"\Outbox\clientSIE.xml");
        }
```

I am expecting the resulting xml to be

```
<Client>
<ClientLocationsList>
<ClientLocation>
data set1
</ClientLocation>
<ClientLocation>
data set2
</ClientLocation>
</ClientLocationsList>
</Client>
```

Instead what I am getting is

```
<ClientLocationsList>
<ClientLocation>
data set1
</ClientLocation>
</ClientLocationsList>
</Client>
data set2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker was able to help me, maybe this will help someone else

I changed

```
changeDoc.Add(elm);
```

To

```
changeDoc.Descendants("Client").First().Element("ClientLocationsList").Add(elm);
```

The problem was just using add is telling the program to add the specified objects with no parent, doing it the updated way tells them I want to insert into the first instance of ClienLocationsList that is a child of Client